# Printing Binary values using nested loops

Tags: java, loops, binary

I need to write a section of code that outputs the binary value up to a user defined number (0-7). 
We can't use .toBinaryString it has to be using loops (for loops preferably).

The output should be three columns with filler zeros. 
Ex) User enters 7

001
010
100
101
110
111

It seems like it should be so simple but I cant seem to get it right.

Comment: `110` is 7, by the way.  You missed 3, `011`.  Anyway, what have you tried so far?

Comment: 110 is 6. Any binary that ends in 0 is even.

Comment: I'm dumb.  `011` is still missing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    String line = "";

    for (int k = 2; k >= 0; k--) {
        line += ((i >> k) & 1) == 1 ? "1" : "0";
    }

    System.out.println(line);
}
```

That uses two for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I would create your own toBinary() function:

```
int toBinary(int x){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    while(x >= 1){
        sb.append(x%2);
        x /= 2;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.reverse().toString());
}
```

Then just use that function to print:

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i++)
    System.out.println( String.format("%03d", toBinary(i)) );
```